# NGINX downloading static file content with the name of the URL?

Tags: nginx

I have a system which allows users to upload files, and also to download them via links, previously, if anyone knew the file name, they could access it by `https://example.com/uploads/filename.example`, however, this was very insecure and I wanted to make it more secure.

I created a file `uploadsController.php` and moved all existing files out of `/uploads/` so the `uploadsController.php` is now the only file in `/uploads/`

`uploadsController.php` is working fine, I have tested it (all it does is checks the user is signed in, and then give them the requested file. My local system was running apache, and had a htaccess file to rewrite all `/uploads/` requests to `/uploads/uploadsController.php`

However, my production system runs on nginx, and I am having some trouble writing a rule that will do the following:

- Serve all requests to `/uploads/` folder to `/uploads/uploadsController.php` regardless of requested file, for example `/uploads/file1.txt`

My current rewrite rule is the following:

```
 location ~* (.*/uploads/.*){
        root /var/www/html/tests_manager/webroot/uploads;
        try_files /uploadsController.php /uploadsController.php;

        rewrite ^$uri$ /uploadsController.php;

        index uploadsController.php
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
```

but this is not working, what is actually happening is the contents of `uploadsController.php` is being placed inside `file1.txt` (or whatever the file name requested is) and then downloaded.

How can I change my rewrite rule to always serve `uploadsController.php` rather than downloading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
rewrite ^/uploads/(.*) /uploadsController.php?file=$1 last;
```

Then in your PHP, you can use:

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
```